# How request_id is being called at django tutorial 03

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I am learning it from Django's official website (making voting app).
I am not stuck process wise but want to understand why in polls/view.py request_id call is working(we have not imported any class then how does it know about this particular id).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views

the only packages installed are 

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

Please help me understand this logic.
Thanks

Comment: `request_id` or `question_id`?

Comment: `request` or `question_id`? `request` always gets filled with the request object and the question_id is implicitly defined in the `urlpatterns`: <int:question_id> will tell that there exists a integer variable called `question_id`.

Comment: sorry for confusion, its question_id i was looking for. now it make sense. So in other words, its deriving from url.py of the same app where view.py is defined, correct ?